# GraphiQL - upload file

Tags: graphql, graphiql

How can we upload files using in-browser GraphQL IDE `GraphiQL`, is that even possible ? (apart from base64 encoded string)

Once I have the file stream / file contents I can create a mulipart request and store on DB or some object-storage service.
But I am not able to figure it out how to provide the file input / how the schema would look like. Is it better to use `graphql-upload` with `Curl` request. Please suggest which is the optimal solution.

Answer (score 39):

I was able to upload a file in my mutation input using [Altair](https://altair.sirmuel.design/). You can use the Add files button to upload a file, then use the upload name on your mutation.

[image]

Comment: Cool! I consumed much time to find this solution. I use Altair extension, which is really awesome! Thanks, @p8ul!

Comment: You are welcome @TaiJinYuan. Happy coding.

Comment: Can someone help me?
After doing the above and writing scalar and resolvers for that I'm getting this error.
"""graphql.error.graphql_error.GraphQLError: Operation data should be a JSON object"""
Need help on server-side implementation.

Comment: This answer should be accepted as a solution for the question.
@p8ul you save my day, lol.

Answer (score 16):

Guys just try **Altair**, saved me a lot of trouble and time. It has extension for chrome too, just like Apollo playground or graphiql, but with file upload option underneath the variables option.

Comment: Could you provide an example with Altair?

Comment: Here's an article explaining how to use it. https://sirmuel.design/working-with-file-uploads-using-altair-graphql-d2f86dc8261f

Answer (score 13):

Currently GraphIQL does not support file uploads. You can use an API tool to do this such as Postman, Insomnia or plan old cURL. The important distinction is that it needs to be a multi-part form upload.

Example request:

```
curl --request POST \
  --url http://localhost:4000/ \
  --header 'accept: application/json' \
  --header 'accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br' \
  --header 'connection: keep-alive' \
  --header 'dnt: 1' \
  --header 'origin: http://localhost:4000' \
  --form 'operations={"query": "mutation UploadFile($file: Upload!) {  uploadFile(file: $file)}",   "variables": { "file": null } }' \
  --form 'map={ "nFile": ["variables.file"] }' \
  --form nFile=@/tmp/testfile
```

Substitute `/tmp/testfile` in the request above with a path to the file you want to upload.